# Finding all possible sub-optimal(not optimal!!!) solutions in optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am writing a CPLEX optimization code to generate a matrix, which takes r and n as the command line arguments, but they may be assumed 2 and 4 for now.

The condition for generating the matrix is that the sum of elements in any row or in any column should equal 10, where the elements are integers between 0 and 10. (i.e. doubly-stochastic matrix)

I turned this condition into the constraint, and generated the matrix, but it only gives a matrix with 10s and 0s.

I think it is because CPLEX always finds the "optimal" solution, but for the problem I want to solve, this is not going to help much.

I want matrices with some 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 0~5 for the rest.

I want to generate all possible matrices satisfying such condition (and some more condition to be added later) so that I could test all of them and exhaust the case.

How can I do that?

I am looking into this solution pool thing, and it is not easy..

Also,

cplex.out() << "number of solutions = " << cplex.getSolnPoolNsolns() << endl;

this gives 1... meaning that there is only one solution, while I know there are millions of those matrices.

If you have any ideas how to generate all the 'sub-optimal' matrices, please help me.

Thank you.

I attached my code in IPGenMat.cpp, and aa.sol was the solution it gave me.

I also copied it here below.

(In short, two questions: 1. how can I find 'less optimal' solutions? 2. how can I find all of such solutions?)

```
#include<ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "Error: " << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int r, n;
        stringstream rValue(argv[1]);
        stringstream nValue(argv[2]);

        rValue >> r;
        nValue >> n;

        int N=n*r;
        int ds = 10; //10 if doubly-stochastic, smaller if sub-doubly stochastic
        IloEnv env;

        try {
            IloModel model(env);

            IloArray<IloNumVarArray> m(env, N);

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                m[i] = IloNumVarArray(env, N, 0, 10, ILOINT);

            }


            IloArray<IloExpr> sumInRow(env, N);

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                sumInRow[i] = IloExpr(env);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
                    sumInRow[i] += m[i][j];
                }
            }

            IloArray<IloRange> rowEq(env, N);

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                rowEq[i] = IloRange(env, ds, sumInRow[i], 10); //doubly stochastic
            }


            IloArray<IloExpr> sumInColumn(env, N);

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                sumInColumn[i] = IloExpr(env);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
                    sumInColumn[i] += m[j][i];
                }
            }

            IloArray<IloRange> columnEq(env, N);

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                columnEq[i] = IloRange(env, ds, sumInColumn[i], 10); //doubly stochastic
            }

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                model.add(rowEq[i]);
                model.add(columnEq[i]);
            }

            IloCplex cplex(env);
            cplex.extract(model);
            cplex.setParam(IloCplex::SolnPoolAGap,0.0);
            cplex.setParam(IloCplex::SolnPoolIntensity,4);
            cplex.setParam(IloCplex::PopulateLim, 2100000000);
            cplex.populate();//.solve();
            cplex.out() << "solution status = " << cplex.getStatus() << endl;
            cplex.out() << "number of solutions = " << cplex.getSolnPoolNsolns() << endl;
            cplex.out() << endl;
            cplex.writeSolutions("aa.sol");

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    cplex.out() << cplex.getValue(m[i][j]) << " | ";
                }
                cplex.out() << endl;
            }
            cplex.out() << endl;

        }

        catch(IloException& e) {
            cerr << " ERROR: " << e << endl;
        }
        catch(...) {
            cerr << " ERROR: " << endl;
        }
        env.end();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try using [PORTA](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/PORTA/)'s `vint` utility or [PPL](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/) for this instead.  CPLEX is geared for optimissation problems, not enumeration problems.

I'd add that, while your problem is a tiny optimisation problem, it's a really huge enumeration problem.  There are likely to be far more solutions that you'd know what to do with.  You might try narrowing down what you want and trying to express that using linear inequalities.

Comment: I am working on a python-based gurobi model, I have a constraint a+b+c+d+e<10
and a,b,c,d,e<=5

which gives the final solution as 5a and 5b. Is there any way to get a solution which gives a distributed/sub optimal value ? (e.g. 2a, 3b 4c, 1d, 2e)

Answer (score 0):

SolnPoolAGap Sets an absolute tolerance on the objective value for the solutions in the solution pool. Solutions that are worse (either greater in the case of a minimization, or less in the case of a maximization) than the objective of the incumbent solution according to this measure are not kept in the solution pool.

So, to obtain sub-optimal solutions you should put a higher value than 0.0
in this parameter

Answer (score 0):

Let's just assume your solution is some matrix with entries `m_i_j`. Express your problem in terms of a set of binary decision variables, e.g. `m_i_j_v` meaning "the matrix at row i and column i has value v". Then after you solve the problem, you can take add another constraint that sums over all the decision variables that are set, and force them to be N-1. This will exclude this as the solution. Rinse an Repeat until the problem becomes infeasible.